# Large scale Laravel App performance when multiple models

Tags: php, performance, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am building a l large scale PHP Laravel App.  It is an app for Developers which consists of many smaller apps/modules.

For example a Bookmarks app similar to PinBoard, a Notebook app similar to Evernote, Code Snippets app, RSS Feed Reader, and about 30 more little apps all in 1 app in which each app acts as a module.

MY question is about performance.  With this many Models and Controllers, etc being loaded, can I not expect good performance on a large user base of this app?

I realize there are too many factors unknown like server settup and more but more so I am asking are things like Models and stuff all loaded on app init or only as needed?  Many times most of the apps/modules will not be used in a request.

I have see some packages which add modules and the modules get there own controllers, models, routes, views, and everything that you wold see in the App folder for each module.  However I am not sure I want to go that route so right now I have it all under the main app like usual.

Comment: Proper caching and you can build anything...

Comment: I don't think there's a helpful answer to this without information. The -number- of models/controllers you have in your entire program is irrelevant. Only the ones that are used on a given request matter, and even then the "size" of those files doesn't really matter.

Comment: Models and controllers are loaded as necessary. You could have a billion models types, but `Foo::all()` is only going to load up one of those models' PHP files.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answers are yes, the app only loads the models/controllers you're using for a given request, and no, the number/size of models and controllers (including those in packages and modules) you have won't negatively affect your app's performance.

The more complex answer is, as always, it depends on how you've written your code; models calling into other models for some piece of business logic, or eager-loading several relationships worth of data without caching, or using an absurd amount of dependency injection in every single controller... but all that's pretty bad app design anyway and not specific to Laravel.

But the most impact you'll see to performance, in my experience, is Eloquent code that tries to be too fancy or inefficiently fetch data out of the database. Check out the documentation to learn about ways to avoid that:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading